# Flexslider not working for my custom theme WordPress

Tags: theme-development, themes, javascript

I add flexslider to my theme homepage http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/bluto/ but it didn'not show on my homepage

Here is the order of js i placed in function.php

```
function theme_name_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style('style-css', get_stylesheet_uri());    
    wp_enqueue_style('ico-moon.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ico-moon.css');   
    wp_enqueue_style('flexslider.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-1.8.3.min.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js');       
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.hoverizr.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.hoverizr.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.isotope.min.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js');       
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.flexslider-min.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js');       
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.nicescroll.min.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js');  
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js');             

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Please suggest  some solution is there any issue regarding my js order or js conflict any suggestion is helpful for me.

Comment: You are getting any error?

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya yes it show error on firebug console  TypeError: $(...).jflickrfeed is not a function

Comment: In which file this error?

Comment: i am getting an error in my flexslider-min.js file

Comment: please suggest some solutions what i am doing wrong.

Comment: So perhaps the issue is with jflickrfeed()? Have you tried removing other plugins to see what the root of the issue could be?

Comment: Thanks @Dan: for your reply there is no such plugin works on my  custom theme.

Comment: Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: This: `/* Flickr feed */
 $('.flickr').jflickrfeed({
  limit : 8,
  qstrings : {
    id : ''
  },
  itemTemplate : '<li>' + '<a href="{{link}}" title="{{title}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image_q}}" alt="{{title}}" /></a>' + '</li>'
 });`

Comment: Thanks @Dan on removing above code its working thank u so much really you are great.

Comment: No problem, maybe you can fix the Flickr code if you need it, but it looks like the JS that would make it work is missing. Either way, I'm glad I could help a bit. Good luck with the theme.

Comment: @Dan: Sorry to disturb you again but my problem remain the same on removing the above code slider works perfectly but there is one section below slider for showing recent post not seen and these recent post coming from widget please suggest solutions why it is not showing. here is the html demo [link] (http://templategraphy.com/demo/bluto/)

Comment: I don't know - I can't see any recent posts that are hidden in the content. I suggest you look at the order of your jS files, and add them in one at a time until you see what's breaking your page.

Comment: Thanks @Dan: for your reply the section i am saying about Recent Works. In which i  am showing my recent post and i am doing the same as you said, one by one remove js files still problem remain the same both sections(slider and recent work) not show at a time. My theme link [link](http://templategraphy.com/wp-demo/bluto/) Please suggest some solutions..

Comment: Finally my problem is solved i missed some div for showing recent post.Thanks everyone for your suggestions.